# Plane of symmetry between two planes

Tags: calculus, matlab, python

For my project, I want to find a symmetrical plane between two planes. I have two equation of planes in form ax + by + cz + d = 0 which intersect each other(at approx. 90 degree). I created these two planes using 3 points to form each plane. Now I want to find a symmetrical plane (i.e approx 45 to each of these planes) which passes through the intersection line of two planes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's indicate with $n_1=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $n_2=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ the normalized normal vectors to the given planes $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z+d_2=0$, thus for the third plane you can choose:

$$n_3=(a_3,b_3,c_3)=(a_1\pm a_2,b_1\pm b_2,c_1\pm c_2)$$

**note**: $\pm$ sign need to be choosen depending on the direction of $n_1$ and $n_2$

and find $d_3$ by the condition that it passes through a point in common with the 2 given planes.

Comment: You need to normalize (or make equal in length) the two normal vectors or the sum won't be a bisector, but with that change, I think this will work. The only issue is that you may need the difference of the normal vectors, since there are two bisecting dihedral planes, and the sum may give you the wrong one (if you care which you get).

Comment: @SteveKass yes you're right, thanks!

Comment: If either vector is short, cross-multiplying by norms instead of normalizing is more stable numerically—it avoids dividing by a small number. I.e., the angle bisectors of vectors $v$ and $w$ are $\|w\|v\pm\|v\|w$.

Comment: @amd thank for this further hints!

Comment: Thank you @gimusi, Steve kass , gmd. This partially solved my problem. The problem which still I am facing is, plane of symmetry which bisects obtuse angle and acute angle. 

As of my understanding, for any intersection of plane there exists one obtuse and one acute angle. How can I create a plane of symmetry with obtuse or acute angle according to reuirement.

I think it depends on ± as indicated by gimusi or direction of n1, n2. Can you please elaborate when to use + or -. I have spent past few days figuring out this.